# Streaming HTTP content over DLNA?

Tags: dlna

file based content served over HTTP, is it possible to have a DLNA server implementation that serves the file to DLNA clients? Some clients (TV) only has a DLNA client, I would like to use DLNA to stream non-local file (basically a DLNA server that proxies connection)

Answer (score 2):

You can put your online video urls in a .m3u8 file and then put this file in your Digital Media Server (DMS) folder. Then DLNA player can play the links inside this file. But not all DLNA Digital Media Players (DMP) support this format.

Comment: this sounds interesting but will not this introduce a gap between each file ?